# Why do assembly call address have 0xFBFFFFFF added to them?

Tags: assembly, call, object-code

Ok so I am writting an assembler for an OS I am developing. It is coming along great I have about all mov instructions and now I want to implement instructions like call and jmp. I really do not have good documentation so I am looking at machine code generated by NASM to find out opcodes and such. I wanted to see what the opcode for call was so I compiled some code that started with a label at the begging. I expected the address after the call opcode to be 00 00 00 00 but it was FB FF FF FF. I thought it had to do with the symbols so I compiled code with call 0x000000 to see what happened and the address was exactly the same (0xFBFFFFFF). Can someone explain this to me I am confused.

Comment: `I really do not have good documentation` - how come? Download the CPU docs from intel.com or amd.com. They have beautiful instruction set tables, descriptions of instruction encoding and operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Showing the actual code you are disassembling would be useful.  Most likely that number is a little-endian negative offset.  0xFFFFFFFB = -5 in 2s complement.  Did you write:

```
Label: call Label
```

If call is a 1-byte opcode with a 4-byte relative offset that would make sense.

Comment: Aaaah, forgot little-endian. Then it could very well just be a direct relative address.

Comment: lol I thought negatives numbers just had one bit infront that represented if it was neg or pos. Lol thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most common form of CALL in 32-bit user mode x86 code is `CALL rel32`, which "calls" into a point at the operand plus the address of the next instruction.  This is a near relative call.

For reference, it would be possible to use an absolute call, but the encoding is 6 bytes instead of 5; the encoding would be `FF 14 XX XX XX XX`.  The extra byte (`14`) tells the instruction to read an immediate displacement which will be used as an immediate.  However, this would need to be rewritten depending on the module base at which your program is loaded; a relative call does not need attention when relocating.

To visualize how this works, as the instruction is executed, this happens:

- `EIP` (the instruction pointer) is incremented to point to the next instruction,
- That address is pushed onto the stack (to provide a return address),
- The immediate (eg. the rel32 value) is added to `EIP`, and
- The next instruction is read from (the new) `[EIP]` as normal.

When this instruction is encoded, it looks like this: `E8 XX XX XX XX`.  From this, you can see that the length of the instruction is 5 bytes.

Because `EIP` is incremented by the length of the instruction, the call will be relative to a point 5 bytes after the start of the instruction.  So, if it happens that the relative  address of your CALL 0x00000000 instruction is 0x00000000, it will be necessary to subtract 5 from `EIP`; your assembler has converted the absolute address to a relative one.

The offset can be negative.  Also, recall that x86 addresses are little-endian.  Thus, the instruction is `E8 FB FF FF FF`.

The consequence of this particular instruction, interestingly, is that `EIP+5` will continually be pushed onto the stack until an exception (`#SS(0)`) is generated.

Comment: Absolute direct near call doesn't exist, only absolute direct far call (9A), or FF /2 near indirect call-register or call-memory (load a new EIP from a pointer). https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call  `ff 14 00` is `call   DWORD PTR [eax+eax*1]` in 32-bit mode.  The next 3 bytes aren't part of the instruction.  (`00 00` is `add [eax], al`).  Try it yourself on https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2

Comment: The rest of the answer does correctly describe `E8` `call rel32`.  The likely result of the eventual stack overflow from this is actually a `#PF` page fault, under a normal OS since they all use a flat memory model with no segment limits.

Answer (score 0):

`call` often comes in various forms, e.g. one that uses an absolute address to jump to, another that jumps relative to the current one. This could be a relative one, although the four bytes probably are not the offset directly.

If in doubt, especially when implementing an assembler, you may want to take a look at the manual or datasheet.